# Angular open new tab

Tags: ios, angular, download, tabs

I have an Angular application that downloads a file to open in a new tab. It works perfectly on any plateform except on IOS where nothing happens. I make the call in the subscribe because during the download I display a spinner before opening the document on a new tab

```
  this.myservice.dowloadFile(id).subscribe((res) =>
  {
    let blob = new Blob([file], {type: "application/pdf"});

    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    let anchor = document.createElement("a");
    anchor.href = url;
    anchor.target = '_blank';
    anchor.click();

    this.loadData = false;
  });
}
```

I don't understand the problem.

Comment: Try `window.open(url, '_blank');`.

Comment: It doesn’t work